# Инициализация char[] структуры элементом массивом const char[][]

Tags: c++

вроде конст чар передаётся в структуру для создания массива, но пишет ошибку. Так же менял мпссив на  неконстантный двумерный массив чар.
Подскажите пожалуйста что может быть не так.

```
const char strings[10][10]{"one","two","three"..."ten"};
struct struct_one{
    char val[20];
    double k;
};
void main(){
    struct_one s1("one", 2323.23);
    struct_one s2(strings[1], 234.3);
    // на этой строке error: array must be initialized with a braсe-enclosed initializer
    std::cout << strings[0] << std::endl;
    //хотя вывод элемента корректный
}
```

Comment: добавил соответствующий конструктор struct_one( const char*, double);  не помню откуда, но в голове отложилось что так (без конструктора) можно создавать структуры(видимо из-за того что паблик поля). Но по сути ведь ничего не изменилось в двух случаях создания структуры const char* первым аргументом.  Единственное отличие что первый выриант это rvalue, а второй  lvalue.

Comment: Перевод ошибки: массив должен быть инициализирован инициализатором, заключенным в фигурные скобки.

Comment: да, на это Я внимание обратил, ошибка для моего кода не обоснована. Ведь массив корректен.

Answer (score 0):

Массивы в C++ являются некопируемыми объектами, а вы по сути передаёте в констуктор массив const char[4] и пытаетесь его присвоить другому массиву, из-за этого и возникает ошибка. Тут без циклического копирования (ну или memcpy, что по сути одно и то же) не обойтись. Ну или используёте std::string вместо масиива char.

```
const char strings[10][10] { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten" };

struct struct_one{
    char val[20];
    double k;
    
    template<size_t S>
    struct_one(const char (&val)[S], double k): k(k) {
        for(int i = 0; i < S; ++i)
            this->val[i] = val[i];
    }
};

int main(){
    char str[] = "one";
    
    struct_one s0(str, 2323.23);
    struct_one s1("one", 2323.23);
    struct_one s2(strings[1], 234.3);
    
    std::cout << s0.val << '\n';
    std::cout << s1.val << '\n';
    std::cout << s2.val << '\n';
    std::cout << strings[0] << '\n';
    std::cout << strings[1] << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Забыл как называется инициализация класса/структуры которая имеет только публичные поля. Так вот, код выше была именно такая инициализация. Но дабавил коснтурктор который принимает const char* и double и всё заработало.

Comment: @PashkaFincler Вы присвоили массиву char указатель на const char?